# Querying a Git subgroup to see what repos exist

Tags: git

I am looking to see if it is possible to query what repos exist in a subgroup.  In essence, I have a subgroup within my main group that contains a number of different repositories.  Some users may not have all the repos cloned locally and I want to avoid people creating duplicates or having to clone everything.

My question is, is it possible to query whether a repo exists in a subgroup.  I know I can run 'get ls-remote' against a specific repo, but that means I must have the repo locally cloned.  Is there a similar thing that I can do with a subgroup to see what repos exist in there or something of that nature?

Thank you.

Comment: What are "group" and "subgroup"? Is this really about that Android-specific tool called `repo` — as per the tag you stuck to your question?

Comment: My apologies, I thought the repo tag would be related to Git.  I updated the post and remove the repo tag.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `git` doesn't now anything about "groups" or "users", and it only knows how to communicate with individual remote repositories.